# differentiability of a complex function and its (real) vector-valued equivalent

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Let f be a complex-valued function of a complex variable, defined as
$$f(z)=u(z) + iv(z),$$
where $z=x+iy$.

Let $g:R^2 \rightarrow R^2$ be its (real) vectored-valued equivalent, i.e.
$$g(x,y)=\begin{bmatrix}u(x,y)\\v(x,y)\end{bmatrix}$$

Does the differentiability of f at a point, say $c=(a,b)$, imply the differentiability of g, or vice versa?  If not, can we add some conditions to make them equivalent?

Thank you very much!

Comment: The "complex" differentiability of $f$ implies the "real" differentiability of $g.$ The other direction fails miserably: e.g., $g(x,y) = (x,-y).$ The other direction works if $g\in C^1$ and the Cauchy Riemann equations are satisfied.

Comment: @zhw.  Thank you, zhw.  For the converse, is it necessary to have $g\in C^1$?  Does it not suffice to have g being differentiable at (a,b) & Cauchy-Riemann Eqs being satisified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A complex-valued function of a complex variable is differentiable if and only if the real and complex parts satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations and are real-differentiable. Therefore, the differentiability of $f$ implies the differentiability of $g$, but not the converse.

N.B. Assume $g$ is differentiable. The derivative matrix with respect to the standard bases is
$$dg = \begin{bmatrix}
u_x & u_y \\
v_x & v_y
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
In terms of complex variables, we would like the derivative to be a complex number. Recall that
$$a + bi \;\;  \leftrightarrow \;\; \begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
-b & a
\end{bmatrix}. $$
Thus $dg$ is the matrix form of a complex number if and only if 
\begin{align*}
u_x &= v_y \\
u_y &= -v_x,
\end{align*}
giving us another derivation of the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Nitin!  So we have  f being differentiable at a point $\Leftrightarrow$ g being differentiable & Cauchy-Riemann Eqs are satisfied at that point ?

Comment: Yes that is correct